# HTML - Text Box - JS Function for Characters Left like SO

Tags: html, webforms, textbox, limit

```
<input type='text' name='one' id='oneID' maxlength="150">
```

i need the JS to display the number of characters left that user can input

[image]

a picture is worth a 1000 words so no more explanation required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind a function to the `onkeyup` event that counts the number of characters entered and displays how much is remaining.

Example:

```
var e = document.getElementById('oneID'),
    f = document.getElementById('countDiv'); // some element where the count will be displayed

e.onkeyup = function() {
  f.innerHTML = (e.maxLength - e.value.length) + ' characters remaining';
}
```

Comment: Do you have the right IDs? Is the DOM ready before you run the js? The code is fine. http://jsfiddle.net/yGdBg/

Comment: i got everything rite but still not working but because its working on jsFiddle.. am gonna accept